# create hive table from json array file format

Tags: json, hive

I have json file format in s3 :

```
{
  "Id" : "123-6789",
  "items" : [ {
    item1: "chair",
    item2: "table"
  }, {
    item1: "shoes",
    item2: "socks"
  }, {
    item1: "phone",
    item2: "charger"
  } ]
}
```

Need to load this into hive table :

```
create EXTERNAL table Items(
Id string,
Items array<struct<item1:string,item2:string>>)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe'
LOCATION 's3://path/';
```

When I do select * from Items, I am getting:

```
Id        items 
123-6789 [{"item1":"chair","item2":"table"},{"item1":"shoes","item2":"socks"},{"item1":"phone","item2":"charger"}]
```

I needed the below output:

```
Id          Item1   Item2

123-6789    chair   table

123-6789    shoes   socks

123-6789    phone   charger
```

I know this is previously asked question, but I didn't get answer what I was expecting.

Answer (score 0):

Use `LATERAL VIEW` and `explode`.

```
select Id,a.item1,a.item2
from
Items LATERAL VIEW explode (result) r as a
```

Alternatively,

```
select 
    Id, 
    get_json_object(Items,'$.item1') as item1,
    get_json_object(Items,'$.item2') as item2
from items
```